# (Discord.js) TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js, typeerror

So here's the code:

```
const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
        
        if (!mutedUser) return message.channel.send()
        if (!message.author) return;
   
        if (!mutedRole) {
            message.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                  name: 'Muted',
                  color: '#6C877C',
                  permissions: ["CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE", "VIEW_CHANNEL"],
                },
              })
                .catch(console.error);
        }
        mutedUser.roles.add(mutedRole).catch(console.error);
```

When I run the bot, I get the error:

```
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731213+00:00 app[Worker.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731236+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/commands/mute.js:69:29)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731236+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Client.<anonymous> (/app/bread.js:111:14)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731238+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731239+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731241+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731242+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731242+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731242+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731243+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
2020-08-14T05:22:08.731244+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

As seen on the code, I add the part where the bot would make a role as when the role is unavailable. But still, it thinks as that the role never exist.

Before this was copied, I aslo wrote the code like this:

```
            if (!mutedRole) {
                guild.roles.create({
                    data: {
                      name: 'Muted',
                      color: '#6C877C',
                      permissions: ["CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE", "VIEW_CHANNEL"],
                    },
                  })
                    .catch(console.error);
            }
```

And the result is still the same. **I also put the bot's role on the most top list of all roles on my test server**. Can anyone find out why?

***I'm currently using discord.js v12 and stable version of node.***

> *Note: full code here: https://github.com/centralomd/breadbot/blob/master/commands/mute.js*

Comment: Where is `mutedUser` defined?

Comment: On top of the full code: https://github.com/centralomd/breadbot/blob/master/commands/mute.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from line 14:

```js
const mutedUser = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
```

If there are no mentions in the `message.mentions.users` Collection, you are trying to get a `GuildMember` using `message.guild.members.get()`.

Discord JS v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use Collection methods such as `Collection.get()` on data structures like `Client.users` and `Guild.members`.

You'll have to change it with:

```js
const mutedUser = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
if (!mutedUser) return message.channel.send("Invalid user.");
```

Note: `message.mentions.users` will get users in other guilds as well. I recommend you to use `message.mentions.members`.